# Django MimeType error

Tags: python, django

guys, I have no idea what is wrong with this error. The code is not something that I wrote so I don't know much about it. Any help is greatly appreciated. I will update the question with any other information that you ask for when it is needed. The code is very hard to read an upload to stack overflow so code posts may take a long time to reply.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.2.214/accounts/login/?next=/

Django Version: 1.11.6
Python Version: 2.7.12
 Installed Applications:
 ('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'tsa.events')
 Installed Middleware:
 ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'tsa.settings.ChapterMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" 
in inner
41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" 
in 
_legacy_get_response
249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" 
in 
_get_response
187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" 
in 
_get_response
185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File " 
/home/serverad/django14_project/my_django15_project/tsa/events/views.py" 
 in login_view
 185.             next=request.GET.get('next', '/'), 
chapters=Chapter.objects.all(), error_msg=error_msg)

File 
"/home/serverad/django14_project/my_django15_project/tsa/events/views.py" 
in render_template
71.     return HttpResponse(txt, mimetype=kwds.get('mimetype','text/html'))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py" in 
__init__
301.         super(HttpResponse, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'
```

Comment: It looks like you are upgrading to a new version of Django. The release notes and deprecation timeline will help explain changes you have to make. If you’re still stuck, searching the error message, e.g. `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mimetype'` will often show you the change you have to make. Since it’s such old code, you may find it easier to get it working on 1.8 LTS (which is currently still supported) instead of jumping straight to 1.11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mimetype` argument was removed in Django 1.7. Use `content_type` instead.

```
return HttpResponse(txt, content_type=kwds.get('mimetype','text/html'))
```